# Need onSave event for One2many relation in ODOO 13 CE

Tags: python, odoo

I'm looking for a solution to achieve an @api.onsave event in ODOO 13 Community Edition.
I can't find any event like this in the code and @api.onchange is not really what I want.

I simply need an event which is being triggered on saving (onExit with Save) a new line-item in a One2many relation, returning the new line-item.

Did I overlook something or is there already any custom code for this I didn't find by myself?
I feel like this is quite a common use-case.

Thank you,
Lars

Comment: What do you excactly mean with "being triggered on saving"? Do you mean pressing the save button on a "parent record" or the save button on the popup (child record form view)?

Comment: Well, from a api-design perspective I suppose pressing the save button on the parent record (= one-side of One2many) would be more correct. My problem would be solved with an onsave event on either case (press parent save button or exit the One2many line-item).

Comment: You've already opened an issue on Odoo github repo. Do you think someone can answer this question really qualified? Seems a bit complex for a SO question IMO.